# Using ConTeXt Commercially ...

Tags: context, licensing

This webpage, http://tex.loria.fr/formats/context/base/readme.pdf, and many others *explicitly* state that ConTeXt must not be used for some purposes; e.g. competing with Pragma ADE.  However, the source code is GPL(ed), which explicitly states the *exact opposite*!  What is the **real** usage policy of ConTeXt, or isn't there one?

Comment: IANAL. This is really confusing. The ConTeXt readme claims the code is licensed under the "Creative Commons GNU GPL." But there is no such thing! Creative Commons has several licenses, none have anything to do with GNU's GPL. Then they claim that ConTeXt can be distributed under the "LaTeX project license." Presumably, they mean the LPPL which is incompatible with the GPL. Then there's a parenthetical about BSD, Ruby, and Apache licenses which makes no sense. Some versions of the BSD and Apache licenses are incompatible with the GPL as well. Then the authors point out they haven't even read...

Comment: I recall there were a cc-gpl thing once, see http://www.google.com/search?q=CC-GPL

Comment: About other points, Hans simply hats licenses and licensing, but I'd understand that as multiple licensing i.e. the code can be used under any of these licenses (dual and triple licensing is not uncommon, see Mozilla or even the new LibreOffice).

Comment: ...the GPL! Finally, they lift the no warranty bit from the BSD license (even though the GPL has a NO WARRANTY section) and insert it. I don't know what to make of this, but it's a mess. In the document you linked, they claim that ConTeXt is in the public domain (contradicting the mess of licenses they claim) and also that it cannot be used to compete with them (which contradicts it being in the public domain). The no competition clause is almost certainly unenforceable given either the licenses or the public domain claim as is requiring permission. Again, IANAL, you should ask one about this.

Comment: @Khaled: I can't actually find the text of such a license. The mreadme.pdf links to [version 2 of the GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.htm). If this was intended to be licensed under several different licenses, it should make that clear. As it stands now, it's a mess.

Comment: @TH. I think that like many programmers, Hans rally doesn't care about licensing in a legal sense. 'Use the **** code and be done with it' seems to be the point he's making (I take much the same attitude, I have to say)

Comment: @Joseph: There's a very simple way to do that: release code in the public domain. Or pick a nonrestrictive license and go with it. I tend to use the BSD license, MIT license, or LPPL with my own work. They're easy to use and easy to understand. I'm not saying that Han's attitude is wrong, but he should take a few minutes and work out how he actually wants to license the code.

Comment: @TH. For much the same reason I use the LPPL: if anyone ever asks, I'm perfectly happy for other licenses to be used but do want some clarity for those who are bothered. I guess what is needed here is an answer from the man himself.

Comment: I've posted a question to the ConTeXt list about this: perhaps a better answer will result.

Comment: @TH: Unfortunately, public domain does not always work in all countries. Using LPPL for ConTeXt code does not sound right. (I wish LPPL were named TPPL ...).

Comment: @Joe Crawford: Can you also point to the **many other** website that state that ConTeXt cannot be used for commercial purposes.

Comment: I suspect that in practice ConTeXt is using the [No problem Bugroff](http://www.reocities.com/SoHo/Cafe/5947/bugroff.html) licence :-).

Comment: @Aditya: IANAL, so I can't speak to public domain not working in all countries (not even sure what that means). As for LPPL not working for ConTeXt, it seems like you're basing that just on the name. I'm not at MIT or BSD and yet those licenses work. The same holds for people who use the Apache License or any other named license, really. The LPPL's provision about not releasing a changed version without a changed name is fairly important to TeX, I think. Certainly better than what is allowed by the GPL. Hans should consider it (despite the name).

Comment: @Aditya: I seem to recall a lot of discussion from way back about Context's use of Wichura's non-free tables macros.  I'm not sure how that got resolved.

Comment: @TH, unless you are directly competing with Berkeley, MIT or Apache you may not have any problem using their licenses, but ConTeXt is a direct LaTeX competitor (though both are free) so it is unlikely for ConTeXt developers to use a license named after their competitor.

Comment: @Khaled: I always see ConTeXt and LaTeX as more complementary than competing - for example, ConTeXt is much stronger if you want design control

Comment: @Khaled: Also, for 'free' software 'competition' seems like a slightly odd term (for example, I've had some very helpful pointers from Taco on LuaTeX, which I want for LaTeX3 but which are modelled on the ConTeXt approach).

Comment: @Joseph: competition is always good (at least that is how I see it), but LaTeX and ConTeXt is far from being complementary it is not TeX and MetaFont; it is more like Gnome vs. KDE, GTK+ vs. Qt, Debian vs. Gentoo, Emacs vs. VIM. All are free but all are competitors still all can have good relationship with each others (except Emacs and VIM) and I don't see any ever using a license named after the other.

Comment: @Khaled: I guess I see the relationship between plain TeX, LaTeX and ConTeXt as similar to that between a racing bike, a tourer and a mountain bike. All are bicycles, but each has a particular specialism. (I'm currently preparing a poster, and suspect I'd be better off with ConTeXt for this job, but I'm not experienced enough to get it right so have stuck with LaTeX even though it's not really the ideal tool.)

Comment: @Khaled: Of course, bicycles don't have licenses :-)

Comment: @Joseph: putting plain aside since it is not up to the competition here (and also written by Knuth which makes it out of competition), ConTeXt and LaTeX are set up to do the same job; document preparation, each has its strengths and weaknesses (though LaTeX has more of the later; I'm biased) but both essentially replace each other (I, for example, use ConTeXt solely to typeset books with almost no graphics, a job LaTeX can do but I prefer ConTeXt for many reasons) and in that sense they are competing.

Comment: @khaled: Too much from someone not affiliated to any.

Comment: @TH: I released a ConTeXt module, that is part of TeX-Live, under public domain. I got an email from Fedora lawyers asking me to give them explicit permission to include the module as part of Fedora; otherwise, they would have to remove my module from TeXLive. Quoting part of that message: "These programs are marked as being in the Public Domain, which is a tricky legal concept in many parts of the world." ... "the ability of a copyright holder to abandon their copyright on a work and place it into the Public Domain is only legally possible in certain jurisdictions"

Comment: @Aditya: Okay, thanks. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is the ConTeXt license status (according to Hans Hagen of Pragma ADE):

> The ConTeXt source code is released under: GNU GPL version 2.

also:

> The ConTeXt manuals that are created by Pragma ADE are (unless stated otherwise in the actual document): Creative Commons Attribution NonCommercial ShareAlike.

and finally:

> The `koeielogos` and `koeieletters` fonts are: Creative Commons Attribution No Derivative Works.

Some other remarks:

The *only* correct website for information about ConTeXt (and especially licensing) is pragma-ade.com. Anything else you may find on the web is not to be trusted.

On the 'Creative Commons' GNU GPL: Creative Commons used to have a special page to explain the GPL in simpler terms than the actual legal text. This is what `mreadme.pdf` refers to, but it seems that that page has now (sadly) been removed from the CC site. I'll make a note to update `mreadme.pdf` at some point (but as the creativecommons.org link inside `mreadme.pdf` still works and correctly points to GPLv2, this is not the highest priority).

On the possibility of alternative licensing: I can understand that the relevant sentence in `mreadme.pdf` is potentially confusing, I'll get Hans to chance it into something like this: 'For alternative licensing options, please contact Pragma ADE.'

About the disclaimer in `mreadme.pdf`: it is a disclaimer, the statement in `mreadme.pdf` that the actual text is in fact taken from a license does not make any difference in its interpretation. Hans and I find the BSD disclaimer a lot easier to understand than the GPL disclaimer, and that is why it is there.

On using ConTeXt to create a system that competes with Pragma ADE: it follows from the above that doing so is perfectly legal. But don't be surprised if neither Hans nor me is willing to offer support to you unless you offer us a billing option.

On using the `LaTeX` project public license: now seriously, do you really think so? Simply because of its name, that license is politically unacceptable, full stop.

Having hopefully answered all questions, can we now forget about this again for half a decade or so? :)

Comment: "On using the LaTeX project public license: now seriously, do you really think so?" Yes, for the reasons I mentioned in my comment. "Simply because of its name, that license is politically unacceptable, full stop." That's your choice. I merely pointed out that it had some stability advantages by requiring people who modify code to call it something else.

Comment: Politically? I'm baffled, really, at that explanation. But that's not me trying to argue for its use. Just curious why it would automatically be ruled out.

Comment: @Will: simple, really: all mention of LaTeX where it is not actually needed nor relevant reinforce the uninformed opinion that "TeX equals LaTeX". Many people assume that because a program mentions X, it must be connected to X.

Comment: yeah okay, i can see your point here. Ta.